# How I can generate transactional synthetic data?

Tags: associations, transactional, synthetic

I am working on Association Rules so I need transactional dataset which is unavailable on UCI repository so I need to generate transactional data. Transactional data is a set of transactions and each transaction have subset of items. Groceries data is a example of Transactional database. 
Let D be a transactional database and T be a transactions t={t1,t2,t3 ...... tn} and I be a set of items I={i1,i2,i3, ..... im} then transactional data looks like

TID      Items
001     i1,i2,i5
002     i5,i6,i8,i10
003     i1,i4
004     i6,i4,i8
Thanks

Comment: I'm not understanding your question, can you try to rephrase?

Comment: Now I think it is clear.

Answer (score 0):

So based off of your definition what it looks like you're trying to do is generate a two dimensional array. In JavaScript you could do something like this:

```
var t = 5, d = [], r = 10, s = 10; 
for(var i=0; i<t; i++){
    d.push([]);
    for(var j=0; j<Math.random()*r; j++){
        d[i].push("i"+Math.floor(Math.random()*s))
    }
}
```

Here we let `t` be the number of transactions, `d` be the two dimensional array of transactions, `r` be the maximum number of transactions in row `i` and `s` be the maximum value of some number in the string (`i`+`someNumber`).  Running the above and printing out `d` (`console.log(d)`) could give you something like this:

```
0 i3, i8
1 i5, i6, i8
2 i1, i2, i5
3 i3, i8 
4 i9, i1, i7, i3, i5
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://www.foyi.co.nz/posts/apps/apps_conjurershiny/) is an opensource app that leverages the R package **conjurer** to generate transactional data.